# 'ME' not valid within a module in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to update a chart from within a module in vb.net;
`Me.Chart1.Series.Add("Profile")`
`Me.Chart1.Series("Profile").Color = Color.LightGray`
`......`
But I keep getting an error message: **'ME' not valid within a module.**
Any workaround would be much appreciated please. Kind regards.

Comment: `Me` references the current instance of an object. A module only has one instance, as such `Me` is not needed (or possible).

Comment: Thanks Anu6is, but how would you update the chart then? Is there an alternative to me. Method? Cheers.

Comment: You either pass the chart to the method it is to be used in or access it via the form `Form1.Chart1.Series...`

Comment: Using `Form1.Chart1` will only work if it was the "Startup Object" or the instance you are looking at onscreen was displayed using the default instance of Form1 via its name. In other words, if Form1 was displayed with `Dim f1 As New Form1` followed by `f1.Show()`, then `Form1.Chart1` will not be the same instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Me` means the current Object or Instance of a Class. `Me` works from within a Form because a Form is a Class AND the Chart is presumably contained by the Form so it is then found and acted upon. The Chart is NOT contained by the Module so `Me` makes no sense here. Additionally, a Module is a special kind of class where everything (including the Module) is SHARED, which is why you also can't use `Me` within it.

The solution is to PASS the Chart into the Module, either storing a reference to it in a Module member, or simply using it via a Parameter in a Method:

```
' ... in the Module ...
Public Sub UpdateChart(ByVal c As Chart)
    c.Series.Add("Profile")
    c.Series("Profile").Color = Color.LightGray
    ' ... other code that use "c" ...
End Sub
```

In the Form, you'd call it with:

```
UpdateChart(Me.Chart1)
```

Comment: Idle_Mind thank you so much, I will give it a try and let you know. Basically, I am trying to update the chart as I go through a Sub within a Module. Not sure yet how to fit the "Public Sub UpdateChart(ByVal c As Chart)" as per your suggestion.

Comment: The answer appears to contain a full set of reasonable advice - which bit are you struggling with? *Not sure yet how to fit the "Public Sub UpdateChart(ByVal c As Chart)" as per your suggestion* - paste the code given, headed "in the module" into the module

Comment: I might be overthinking it. I will have a go at it tonight when I get home and advise either way. Thank you all.

Comment: Idle_Mind it works and your workaround has actually helped me tidy up my code into modules. Thank you so much for your prompt and accurate response. Kind regards.